# Datadog not recognizing resource names in a request

Tags: go, monitoring, datadog, apm

I am getting start with DataDog agent for my Go application. I am looking at implementing APM tracing to identify how the API request flows and the functions that are being triggered.

In my current app, I have a route that calls another function. The end goal here is to record both the route and the function as two separate resources (in addition the recording them as a span graph). However, currently, only the API call gets recorded in DataDog as a resource but the function call does not.

What I want to do is capture both of them in the Traces list so that they I can generate visualizations based on specific resources (for example: log_func)

My **main.go** file is uploaded here https://gist.github.com/baljit92/87870f38cf20df9e2a30f30e4993de48

Here is a screenshot of what I see on Datadog APM. As per the screenshot, log_func only appears under Span List and not under the Traces list.
[image]